# Weird issues with image resizing in JavaScript (problems only in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, css, image, firefox, cross-browser

Code:

```
function resizeImage()
{
    // this just dynamically changes the width of the wrapper depending on the popup width
    // to properly calculate what size should the image be fit into
    var largeWidth = gallery.offsetWidth - 300;
    setStyle(div, "width: " + largeWidth + "px");
    maxWidth = div.offsetWidth;
    if (maxWidth < 300) // can only happen if CSS max-width is not supported
    {
        maxWidth = 300;
    }
    maxHeight = div.offsetHeight - 60;
    if (maxHeight < 240)
    {
        maxHeight = 240;
    }
    var style = "width: " + ((origWidth > maxWidth) ? maxWidth : origWidth) + "px;";
    setStyle(img, style); // at this point the image is fit into the wrapper by width, still need to check the height
    if (img.height >= maxHeight) // the height is out of bounds
    {
        style = "height: " + maxHeight + "px;";
    }
    else // height is not enough, pad it by half (hack for vertical-align: middle...)
    {
        style += 'padding-top: ' + Math.floor((maxHeight - img.height) / 2) + "px";
    }
    setStyle(img, style);
}
```

The problem:
Every browser I tested (IE 7,8,9 document modes (padding and margin: auto doesn't work in Quirks Mode so no centering there), Safari 5.1.2, Opera 11.61, Chrome 17.0.963.66) does this job reasonably well, padding is always correct no matter how fast I switch the images (there are thumbnails to the right of the big image and images can be switched using arrow keys aswell). BUT Firefox 10.0(.2) has a weird problem: when you switch images, more often than not the padding/height is broken (sometimes padding is >3x more than it should be or it isn't there at all, or height doesn't switch etc.). Is there a problem in the way Firefox resizes images or something? Because I can't figure out why only Firefox does this (even the damn IE works perfectly compared to FF).

If there is need for additional info, ask away. I could, of course, just add a link to the actual page, but I'm not sure if it is allowed so I'll refrain from doing that for now.

Edit: ok, I've managed to get a little closer to the problem (I think). When I change the source of the image (img.src) and console.log the img.width and img.height, the source changes but the width and height DO NOT!! And it happens only in Firefox! WTF is that?

Comment: use developer console to track style of the dom elements

Comment: You could use percentage units to set the width of the image, without script at all.

Comment: @Teemu - how do you imagine that? It's not just about width, if the image is wide then sure, but there are some limits (don't zoom in if width/height <= 450px) and I need to change only the width OR height, not both. If the image is 400x400 and the wrapper is 400x300, I need to set only height and not width.

Comment: can you give any link so we can easily track on the wrong working thing..

Comment: Here's a link: http://www.dateks.lv/cenas/3/58623_hewlett_packard_compaq_presario_cq57_381er_15_6_1_65ghz_4gb_500gb_dos.php . Click on any of the images to open the gallery. I've already changed the code slightly, but the issue is still there. It seems that for some weird reason Firefox alone "remembers" the CSS style of the previously viewed picture and applies it to the current image without taking JS into consideration. When I hover over the thumbnail of the current image again, the CSS gets fixed.

Comment: please add the snippet where you call the resizeImage() function on the hover of the image... i guess the problem is there somewhere

Comment: @ggzone - see my first answer to Boris Zbarsky

Answer (score 1):

When you change .src the spec says the new image is loaded async.  This is true even if it's been "preloaded".  What that means is that the width/height, which depend on the image that's currently loaded, change async as well.

So if you set .src and immediately read the width/height you should get the old image dimensions, per spec.  Use an onload handler to wait for the image to actually load?

Comment: http://www.dateks.lv/js/gallery.js?v=75 - here's the exact javascript file that does the "magic". AS you can see, resizeImage is called directly only when the popup is being resized (no image switching here), in other cases it is called after the next image is already preloaded (switchImage() function). I'd expect the browser to know that if you switch the `src` attribute of the current image to a different, already preloaded image, it would automatically change the image width/height aswell, but it seems that this isn't the case with Firefox.

Comment: Again, the spec says the width/height change asynchronously, even if the image being switched to is already preloaded.

Comment: So then when am I supposed to know the real width/height of the image??

Comment: When onload fires, like I said.